# Как лучше привести к типу float?

Tags: c++

Что лучше: `-float(x)` или `float(-x)`, где `x` имеет тип `unsigned short`?

Comment: лучше для чего?

Comment: 1 лучше. Делать - к беззнаковому как-то некрасиво, а так разницы нет https://godbolt.org/g/IQG8VZ

Comment: @user227660  Как говорится, на вкус и цвет товарищей нет.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для `unsigned short` не имеет значения(при `sizeof(short)` < `sizeof(int)`), т.к. Ваше выражение `float(-x)` сначала приведёт `x` к `int`, сделает его отрицательным, а потом приведёт к `float` — никаких проблем.

Проблемы начнутся, если у вас тип `unsigned int` и «выше» — в этом случае вариант с `float(-x)` даст не то, что Вы ожидаете, т.к. сначала будет посчитан новый `x` исходя из [формулы](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#8) `2^n - x`, а потом это будет преобразовано во `float`; где `n` это разрядность исходного типа(в нашем случае `int`).

Поэтому, во избежание проблем, лучше всегда придерживаться первого варианта(`-float(x)`), как наиболее безопасного и лучше отражающего намерение.

Comment: ну или если у вас компилятор 16-битный) например borland C...

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй, первое лучше передает намерение программиста. Формально применение минуса к `unsigned` выглядит не очень красиво...

Comment: кстати это просто некрасиво или UB?

Comment: @pavel Этого не скажу, но float(unfigned) - не должно быть таковым точно :)

Comment: если sizeof(int) == sizeof(short) то будет плохо http://ideone.com/VMtrpr

Comment: @pavel Здесь нет никакого UB.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow просто если это сделать с интом то результаты разные. Вот и спросил поэтому

Comment: @pavel Конечно важно, чтобы результат был представим в заданном типе. Поэтому лучше сначала перевести в float, а затем применять унарный минус.